# Aplicar un INSERT en una consulta con UNION

Tags: sql-server

Inserto información en tablas temporales de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * INTO #AR_TABLA_TEMP_1 FROM PERSONAS
```

Tengo que hacer lo mismo pero con una consulta que tiene la sentencia `UNION`

```
SELECT *
FROM AR_SALDOS_TOTALES_CVEN
UNION
SELECT 'TOTAL' AS TERRITORIAL,
       SUM(ENEM_18) AS  ENEM_18,
       SUM(FEBM_18) AS  FEBM_18,
       SUM(MARM_18) AS  MARM_18,
       SUM(ABRM_18) AS  ABRM_18,
       SUM(MAYM_18) AS  MAYM_18,
       SUM(JUNM_18) AS  JUNM_18,
       SUM(JULM_18) AS  JULM_18,
       SUM(AGOM_18) AS  AGOM_18,
       SUM(SEPM_18) AS  SEPM_18,
       SUM(OCTM_18) AS  OCTM_18,
       SUM(NOVM_18) AS  NOVM_18,
       SUM(DICM_18) AS  DICM_18
FROM AR_SALDOS_TOTALES_CVEN
```

Esto es posible ? y si lo es como seria lo estructura correcta ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más rápida es hacer que la información se cargue como una subconsulta desde el from.

```
SELECT *
INTO #AR_TABLA_TEMP_1
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM AR_SALDOS_TOTALES_CVEN
    UNION
    SELECT 'TOTAL' AS TERRITORIAL,
       SUM(ENEM_18) AS  ENEM_18,
       SUM(FEBM_18) AS  FEBM_18,
       SUM(MARM_18) AS  MARM_18,
       SUM(ABRM_18) AS  ABRM_18,
       SUM(MAYM_18) AS  MAYM_18,
       SUM(JUNM_18) AS  JUNM_18,
       SUM(JULM_18) AS  JULM_18,
       SUM(AGOM_18) AS  AGOM_18,
       SUM(SEPM_18) AS  SEPM_18,
       SUM(OCTM_18) AS  OCTM_18,
       SUM(NOVM_18) AS  NOVM_18,
       SUM(DICM_18) AS  DICM_18
    FROM AR_SALDOS_TOTALES_CVEN
) X
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas crear tu Insert de una manera diferente para que puedas usar el Union:

```
INSERT INTO INTO #AR_TABLA_TEMP_1(valor1,valor2)
SELECT valor1,valor2
FROM AR_SALDOS_TOTALES_CVEN
UNION
SELECT valor1,valor2
FROM AR_SALDOS_TOTALES_CVEN
```

Espero y te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Lo que pasa que de la manera que lo hago la estructura se crea sola en el INSERT como la información la estoy tomando de otra tabla es posible que a esa tabla le agreguen columnas y la sentencia ya no va a funcionar tendría que modificar la tabla temporal para que tenga los mismos campos

Comment: Ha oks, la tabla se crea junto con el select, yo pensé que ya la tenias creada con sus campos definidos, entonces definitivamente mi opción no te sirve.